# Wrong link in the election pages

Tags: bug, status-completed, election, meta, hyperlinks

There is an issue with the "Meta" link in the [current election](https://movies.stackexchange.com/election/2)  and [previous election](https://movies.stackexchange.com/election/1)  pages.

In the description below, the "Meta" link is pointing to
"https://movies.meta.com/tags/election", but it supposed to be "https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/election".

> For questions about the election process itself, visit [Meta](https://movies.meta.com/tags/election).

Screenshot for reference:

> [image]